# I was trying to compute $\sum_{j=0}^{m} 3^j {m \choose j}$, but don't know where to start

Tags: discrete-mathematics

compute $\sum_{j=0}^{m} 3^j {m \choose j}$. Then, use the binomial theorem to verify the result.

Comment: Please edit the title to make it more informative.

Comment: how can I edit it?

Comment: To edit, click the "edit" button under your question. Make it informative, so that people seeing the title alone, have a sense of what you're conveying in the main body.

Comment: thanks, I put my problem in the title.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$4^m=(3+1)^m=\sum_{j=0}^m{m\choose j}\cdot3^j\cdot1^{m-j}=\sum_{j=0}^m{m\choose j}\cdot3^j$$ or $$\sum_{j=0}^m{m\choose j}\cdot3^j=\sum_{j=0}^m{m\choose j}\cdot3^j\cdot1^{m-j}=(3+1)^m=4^m$$

Comment: can you make it more clear, I still don't get why is 4^m in there and what does that C mean?'

Comment: OP wanted to compute it and then "use binomial theorem to verify". So shouldn't some other method be used also?

Comment: @mathLee It is obvious from context that $C^j_m = \binom{m}{j}$.

Comment: So $\sum_{j=0}^{m} 3^j {m \choose j}$ = 4^m finally? It is a backward computation?

Comment: just wondering why put a 1^(m-j) in there?

Comment: $(a+b)^m=\sum_{j=0}^m{m\choose j}\cdot a^j\cdot b^{m-j}$ . See [binomial theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem).